# How can i put a string with an ampersand in an xml file with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, cdata

I'm trying to include a URL to an image in an XML file, and the ampersands in the URL query string are getting stripped out:

```
bgdoc.xpath('//Master').each do |elem|
  part = elem.xpath('Part').inner_text
  image = imagehash[part]
  image = "" if image.blank?
  elem.xpath('Image').first.content = "<![CDATA[#{image}]]>"
  puts elem.xpath('Image').first.content
end
```

bgdoc is getting written out with the help of Builder later on. But not the individual elements, it's getting inserted all at once. That makes it a different case than a similar question posted on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`create_cdata`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-create_cdata) to create a CDATA node and then [`add_child`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-add_child) to add it to the document, just assigning a string to `content` will leave you with `&lt;!CDATA...` in your XML and that's not very useful.

A short example should illustrate the process:

```
xml   = '<Master><Image></Image><Image></Image></Master>'
bgdoc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
cdata = bgdoc.create_cdata('/where?is=pan&cakes=house')
bgdoc.xpath('//Image').first.add_child(cdata)
```

Then, if you `bgdoc.to_xml` you'll get something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Master>
    <Image><![CDATA[/where?is=pan&cakes=house]]></Image>
    <Image/>
</Master>
```

I think that's the sort of result you're looking for. However, if you just assign a string to `content`:

```
bgdoc.xpath('//Image').first.content = '<![CDATA[/where?is=pan&cakes=house]]>'
```

Then you get this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Master>
    <Image>&lt;![CDATA[/where?is=pan&amp;cakes=house]]&gt;</Image>
    <Image/>
</Master>
```

and that doesn't even have a CDATA node.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace the ampersand with its xml/html character code ? It should be working.

The code for the ampersand is:
`&amp;`

[Click here for more information about character codes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: The real problem here is that AKWF is not actually adding a CDATA node to their document, they're just adding a string which will be XML-encoded to escape `<`, `>`, and `&`. Using `&amp;` instead of `&` will yield `&amp;amp;` in the XML.

Comment: That's exactly what happened.