# Inserting unescaped URLs with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, entities

I have a script that inserts URLs into existing XHTML pages. The URLs have tracking codes with ampersands, and Nokogiri automatically replaces them with the escaped version `&amp;`. I understand why, but the escaped URL means that the tracking doesn't work, as the tracking code has been changed.

I've checked out [How to save unescaped & in nokogiri xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906705/how-to-save-unescaped-in-nokogiri-xml), [How can i put a string with an ampersand in an xml file with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580803/how-can-i-put-a-string-with-an-ampersand-in-an-xml-file-with-nokogiri), and [Preventing Nokogiri from escaping characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252330/preventing-nokogiri-from-escaping-characters), but I'm not quite sure how using the builder or using cdata works in the context of what I'm trying to do.

Here's a simplified version of what I am currently doing (with `main_link` being pulled from an external source):

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("file.xhtml"))
link = doc.css("a")[0] # the actual file may contain multiple links, not just one
main_link = "http://www.url.com/"
tag = "?blah&blah=blahblah"
link["href"] = main_link + tag
new_content = doc.to_xml
File.open("new_file.xhtml", "w") { |f| f.write(new_content) }

#=> <a href="http://www.url.com/?blah&amp;blah=blahblah">link</a>
```

I've done this, which works:

```
content = File.read("file.xhtml")
content.gsub!("&amp;","&")
File.open("updated_file.xhtml", 'w') { |file| file.write(content) }

#=> <a href="http://www.url.com/?blah&blah=blahblah">link</a>
```

but I'd like to avoid reopening/resaving files, since I'm working with a lot at one time and want to be as efficient as possible.

Is this doable with Nokogiri? Should I be looking elsewhere to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to avoid reopening/resaving files, why not put the `gsub!` code in the original script (`new_content.gsub!(...)`)?

Comment: @JordanRunning yeah that's actually what I was doing in my code (I displayed it differently in my question just to make it clearer), but I just wasn't sure if there was a better way that avoided `gsub` altogether